# If $p$ and $q=2p−1$ are primes, and $N=pq,$ then $N$ is pseudo-prime for all possible bases $b$ that are quadratic residues modulo $2p−1.$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Being $n \in \mathbb Z,$ $n$ is said to be pseudo-prime with respect to the base $b$ if it is compound and also verifies the congruence $b^{n−1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$  where $n|b^{n-1}-1$.

Show that if $p$ and $q=2p−1$ are primes, and $N=pq,$ then $N$ is pseudo-prime for all possible bases $b$ that are quadratic residues modulo $2p−1$.

I can solve it when given concrete examples, but I am struggling with being able to generalize this, as asked here.

For example, $91\equiv 13\cdot 7$, then $13\equiv 2\cdot 7-1$,  $$\begin{equation*}         \begin{cases}         4^2 = 9^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}\\         5^2 = 8^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13})\\         6^2 = 7^2 \equiv 10 \pmod{13}\\         \end{cases}     \end{equation*}$$

so \begin{equation*}         \begin{cases}         4^2 = 9^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}\\         5^2 = 8^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}\\         6^2 = 7^2 \equiv 10 \pmod{13}.\\         \end{cases}     \end{equation*}

But I do not know the general case for $p$ and $2p-1$.

Comment: Rosa, por favor, ¿puedes preguntar si esto es inglés?

Comment: If p and $q = 2p − 1$ are primes, and $N = pq$, then $N$ is pseudo-prime for all possible bases b that are quadratic residuals modulo $2p − 1$.                                                  
 A quadratic remainder is that there exists an $x$ ​​such that $x^2 \equiv q (mod n)$ .                       Being n belonging to the integers, n is said to be pseudo-prime with respect to the base b if it is compound and also verifies the congruence $b^{n−1} \equiv 1(modn)$ where $n|b^{n-1}-1

Comment: Being n belonging to the integers, n is said to be pseudo-prime with respect to the base b if it is compound and also verifies the congruence: $b^{n-1} \equiv 1\pmod n$ when $n\\mid b^{n-1}-1$... ?

Comment: yes, This property is a particular case of Fermat's Little Theorem

Comment: Please advise as to whether I've translated your post correctly.

Comment: But I don't yet see what your question is, Rosa.

Comment: sorry, my english level is bad

Comment: shows that if p and q=2p−1 are primes, and N=pq, then N is pseudo-prime for all possible bases b that are quadratic residuals modulo 2p−1.

Comment: No problema, Rosa.  Yo comprendo.

Comment: thanks for everything

Comment: I will solve it for concrete examples, but I won't generalize it

Comment: Gracias por su cooperación, @Rosa.

Comment: for example: 91 = 13*7, luego 13 = 2*7-1  \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
        4^2 = 9^2 \equiv 3 (mod \quad 13)\\
        5^2 = 8^2 \equiv 12 (mod \quad 13)\\
        6^2 = 7^2 \equiv 10 (mod \quad 13)\\
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}

Comment: so, \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
        3^{90} \equiv 1 (mod \quad 91)\\
        12^{90} \equiv 1 (mod \quad 91)\\
        10^{90} \equiv 1 (mod \quad 91)\\
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}

Comment: but now I don't know for the general case p and 2p-1

Comment: Gracias, @Rosa.

Comment: Tenga en cuenta que $\equiv$: `\equiv`, y $n\pmod m$: `n \pmod{m}`. (Solo algunos consejos para formatear las matemáticas.) :-)

Comment: do you know how it would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $p$ and $q:=2p-1$ are prime, then $N:=pq$ satisfies the property that if $$a \equiv u^2 \pmod{q},$$
and $p,q\nmid a$, 
then 
$$a^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{N}.$$

One solution is to use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). In this context,
it says that it suffices to show both 
$$a^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
and
$$a^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{q}.$$

For the first statement,
$$
a^{N-1}=a^{p(2p-1)-1}=a^{2p^2-p-1}
=a^{(2p+1)(p-1)} \equiv 1\pmod{p},$$
since $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ by Fermat's little theorem.

For the second statement, 
$$
a^{N-1}=a^{q(q+1)/2-1}
\equiv
u^{q(q+1)-2}
= u^{q^2+q-2}
= u^{(q-1)(q+2)}
\equiv 1\pmod{q}
$$
again by Fermat's little theorem, since $u^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.